# What happens to your residency rights when you lose/renounce your citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

This is a generic question involving a situation when the original citizenship is lost/renounced due to obtaining a citizenship of a different country (either due to one of the countries not allowing dual citizenship, or simply voluntarily).

What would normally happen to residency rights in the country where citizenship is lost? Are there examples where it is possible to retain a permanent right to reside? Or a temporary right to reside (being able to upgrade to a permanent one in the future)?

If this happens while you're in the country where you lost your citizenship, would you need to leave/be deported?

Comment: This question is too broad.  The provisions for these circumstances vary widely from one country to another.

Comment: @phoog :( my thinking was that if Travel.SE seems to be good with broad questions like "[What's the longest distance that can be traveled by only using free transportation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151994/42483)" that received 25 answers (people seem to be enjoying answering them too, especially the likes of [What's the longest scheduled public bus ride in the world?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56357/42483) and multiple other examples) then Expatriates.SE might be not to dissimilar unless I'm wrong. Otherwise it could be treated as a canonical question?

Comment: But essentially I was just looking for examples of what happens in these cases regarding my question.

Comment: But there is a single correct answer to "What's the longest distance that can be traveled by only using free transportation?"  The only correct answer to this question is either "it depends" or a list of countries that give former citizens easier access to residential rights.  I also have to say that I find those trivial questions on travel to be rather tiresome.  I thought about answering this question but the answer is quite trivial and unsatisfying, so I voted to close instead.

Comment: Highly dependent on the Residence laws of the country of residence and how the citizenship being renounced. For some countries it is effected immediately, but must be confirmed (which can take a long time). When nationalization may only done after confirmation - then during that time you are stateless and need a new residence permit where the residence permit is based on the passport.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but when Conrad Black renounced his Canadian citizenship he lost his right to live and work  in Canada, and had to reapply for a visa to work there in the same way as anyone else.